# How can i get full soap request (header and xml body)

Tags: c#, web-services

I developed a soap web service by c#.Net

but i need to get a whole soap request. because some requsts are not in .net correct form and i need to have whole XML request (header and body) to read it full.

How can i get full soap request (header and xml body)?

Comment: How is your service implemented? ASMX? WCF? An HTTP handler?

Comment: My web service is ASMX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend ASP.NET web services with a `SoapExtension` - this gives you low-level access to the SOAP message stream. You could use this to inspect and then transform input messages as required. Here's an old MSDN article about SOAP extensions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188761.aspx

If the client can call your WebMethod successfully but you just want to inspect the original message you could try reading Request.InputStream; that would be a lot simpler than implementing a SoapExtension.